# Spring Security и нормализованная база данных

Tags: java, spring, jdbc, spring-security

В Spring Security класс JDBCDaoImpl по умолчнаию использует в качестве первичного ключа имя пользователя, а не id, что у меня (джуна) вызволо недоумение. Если я не ошибаюсь, то нормализованная бд для хранения пользователей состоит из 3-ёх таблиц:

1. [таблица пользователей] id,username,password
2. [таблица ролей] id, имя роли
3. [связующая таблица] id пользователя - id роли

Как я понял, для того, чтобы заставить Spring Security работать с первичным ключём id, нужно писать свою реализацию JDBCDaoImpl или UserDetailsService. 
Подскажите в чём я прав/не прав. Меня смутило, что разработчики Spring Security не сделали встроенную реализацию через id, возможно, это и не нужно и я просто этого не понимаю.

P.S.
В Spring Security реализована работа с пользователями через бд, но на основе двух таблиц, а не трёх, как в моём примере. 
1 - ая это имя пользователя/пароль и тд, а во второй имя пользователя - имя роли.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Лучше не гадать, как устроена схема для стандартной реализации JdbcDaoImpl, а просто посмотреть в документации: https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/3.0.x/reference/appendix-schema.html

В вашей реализации уникальными являются и id, и username одновременно - не бывает двух пользователей с одинаковым username. В результате получается дублирование информации (дополнительная нагрузка на дисковую и систему), мусор в базе (надо отдельно проверять уникальность username) и мусор в коде клиента.

Вместо этого стандартной схеме spring security из этих колонок оставлена только одна - username.

Промежуточная таблица у вас получилась тоже как следствие наличия id. Вместо этого в Spring Security таблица authority индексируется по композиции username+authority - именно в таком виде, в котором их чаще всего зовут в реальных приложениях.

Если вы понимаете что да - вам обязательно нужен id - вы просто идете и реализуете это поведение. Это архитектурный вопрос, в архитектурных вопросах вы наедине со своей идеей. Всегда нужно знать, что хочешь конкретно ты, а не бездумно копировать стандартное поведение со Spring Security или откуда-то еще. Поэтому в вопросе было очень неплохо также иметь и аргументацию за использование id, чтобы отвечающие могли отталкиваться от нее.

Comment: Огромное спасибо за ваш ответ, я перед тем как задать вопрос ознакомился с документацией и конкретно с той страницей, которую вы прислали. По существу, когда мы делаем web приложение не разумным ли считается делать так, чтобы название ролей потом можно было поменять с минимальными правками? Те в системе из трёх таблиц менялось бы только в 1 таблице и только 1 строка, а в системе из двух таблиц в случае изменения названия роли придётся менять очень много строк, подскажите где я не прав или чего не понимаю?

Comment: Видимо, этот вопрос решается через группы пользователей?

Comment: Вопрос перешел в дискуссию, рекомендую перейти сюда:
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35163/discussion-on-question-ru-488340
Объясните подробней в чате, какие именно строки вы собрались менять.

Comment: Хорошо, перешёл